# как добавить класс элементу при hover на другой

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть блок при :hover на который выезжает другой блок, в который вложен 3й блок. 
При :hover на первый блок к 3ему блоку должен добавится class="bounce" и срабатывать анимация из wow animated. Подскажите как реализовать? Пробовал при помощи jQuery но не знаю как выбрать 3й блок, при :hover на первый, а если добавлять через собитие onmouseover
то класс добавляется, но анимация не срабатывает.

```
    <script>
    $(".content-item").hover(
        function () { $(this).addClass("bounce") },  
        function () { $(this).removeClass("bunce") } 
    );
      </script>

<div class="content-item">
  <div><span>Lorem ipsum do sit</span> 
        <div class="bye_cruize wow">
            <a href="#"><span>BYE CRUIZE</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".content-item").hover(function () {
  $(this).children().children().toggleClass("bounce");
});
```

Comment: <script>
  $(".content-item").hover(
   function () { $(this).children().children(".bye_cruize").addClass("bounce")},
   function () { $(this).children().children(".bye_cruize").removeClass("bounce");
  });
</script>   немного доработал под нужды, подскажите как сделать так чтобы анимация срабатывала при каждом hover, класс добавляется а анимация только 1 раз срабатывает.

Comment: @Vova Kotsiubenko Код можно сократить ещё, смотрите выше на toggleClass(), а вот с анимацией надо смотреть как она прописана. Я этого  wow animated не видел в глаза. ))